# Mind mapping-like app from Ubuntu Software Center - I don't remember its name

Tags: 18.04, software-center

I have a silly question. During my last installation of Ubuntu I found an interesting piece of software, it looked like a mind mapping software, and as a demo it had a mind map of Mars colonisation. I never actually used it, so I don't really remember its name.

It was on my older laptop, but its hard disk died a few days ago. I have installed Ubuntu on my second laptop (the same version - 18.04 LTS) and I tried to find it.

It was in one the "recommended" tabs in Ubuntu Software Center, but it isn't there now :(

The only two things I remember is this "Mars colonisation" demonstrational mindmap, and its logo/icon - which looked like The Sims green crystal, but was totally blue.

Does anyone know what is its name?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean [Zenkit](https://zenkit.com/).

It is not a "simple" mind mapping software, rather a project management tool to manage milestones, to-do's etc. (Yes, these can then be displayed as a mind map.)